# Android studio: How to dynamically display and refresh a custom list which is horizontally and vertically oriented at the same time?

Tags: java, android, list, refresh, display

So I've been developping an app on Android Studio and at some point I need to display couples of values composed of texts and images but I have some issues with the display.
Let's say here that I want a list of fruit names associated with a picture, I'd like to display it that way :
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPZY8.png)

Each image and its related text is in linearlayout, so it's a list of linearlayouts.
The "add fruit" button open an alerdialog where the text and the image can be chosen, by clicking the 'ok' button in the alertdialog the name and the image are saved in a sqlLite database (which I already have programmed), and the linearlayout has to be added in the current list as the dialog is dismissed.

So the issue here is that:

1. I don't really know **how to dynamically display each one of these linearlayouts [in this specific order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uz9S5.png).**
2. I don't know how to make it so that **when a new fruit is added and the dialog dismissed, the list in the activity is refreshed directly**.

---

I've been thinking of using a listview but listviews are only horizontal OR vertical but in this case I kind of need a mix of both.

Another idea was to delete the layout containing all the linearlayouts (all the list) when a new fruit was added, and then take my database to create all the linearlayouts again. But dynamically I don't think it will work, the refresh won't be done (?)

My last idea was to create a fragment and use my database in the onCreateView method to display every elements. And to refresh it, I'll just detach and attach again the fragment to the activity each time I add a new element.

---

I don't think my ideas are the optimal or even a correct way to do it, I've been struggling with it for a while. If you have any suggestions or ideas to help me, it would be great :)

Comment: GridView can do the trick and you can just notifydatasetChanged the adapter of gridview when you add item on the List.

Comment: Oh great ! :o I didn't know that it exists. Thanks a lot !